# Unable to open Anki on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

Trying to use Anki 2.1.35.While trying to open it,the following error arises-

```
    Qt info: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. 
Qt fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Anki 2.1.26 runs fine though.Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: If Anki won't start, run 'QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 anki' in a terminal to see if any error messages appear. Chances are you are missing a library that Anki requires, and the error message should indicate what is missing. Installing the library via your distro's tools (eg apt-get) should fix the problem.

Comment: @BernardDecock Thank you for your help.I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in the newest Qt6-based version (at the time of writing it's 23.10.1), and Ubuntu 23.10 + LXQT.

Starting `anki` in the terminal yielded:

```
Qt info: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. 
Qt fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Starting the application in the debug mode `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 anki` was a little bit more helpful:

```
Qt debug: "/usr/local/share/anki/lib/PyQt6/Qt6/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" cannot load: Cannot load library /usr/local/share/anki/lib/PyQt6/Qt6/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-cursor.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) 
Qt debug: QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/usr/local/share/anki/lib/PyQt6/Qt6/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /usr/local/share/anki/lib/PyQt6/Qt6/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-cursor.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
```

Install the missing library to fix the issue: `sudo apt install libxcb-cursor0`